# Solve equation with logarithms

Tags: equation, logarithm

I want to solve the following equation: log(log(y))=1/(x**2), and I want to get y as a function of x. How can I make a program in phyton in order to to this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: u try -- we try

Comment: You write code. That's how. Writing is your job, we (maybe) try help fix what do you do end up writing.

Comment: python, not phyton

Comment: Try first with pencil and paper

Answer (score 0):

By rearrangement, `y = exp(exp(x ** -2))` will do it.

Note that this is a very *strong* function of `x`. Are you sure your starting equation is correct? (The log10 log10 of the number of particles in the universe is less than 2).